# MS Access Default Images Used On Access Forms and Reports (header section)

Tags: images, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

From within Access, if you click on the `Create` tab and then click on the `Form` button, it creates a basic form with all the fields from your table/query. In the top left hand corner, an image always appears in the `Form Header` section.

[image]

Are these images stored some where locally, that I could insert additional images? These images appear to be default, as they are loaded after the wizard is finished.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a different image choose Design -> Logo and pick up the image.
Access resizes the image and inserts it in the header of the form. The image is an Auto_Logo object. I don't know where the default image is.

Comment: Thanks, while I know how to insert an image, I'm mainly looking for where these default images are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow the instructions here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-43.html and specifically create a default database.